# How to respond to an unsolicited offer to publish work I have posted on arXiv?

Tags: publications, journals, arxiv

Approximately one year ago, I submitted some of my research work to [arXiv](http://arxiv.org/).

Recently, I got an email from [Lambert Academic Publishing](https://www.lap-publishing.com/) saying that they are interested in publishing this work and stating that their services are free of charge for authors.

I don't have much idea about different journals and publications. It would be great if someone can project the benefits of moving to publish in such academic publications. As arXiv already provides open access, is there any need of publishing somewhere else also?

Comment: Generally speaking, if you publish in more journals, more people will see it. But be careful there is no problem with double submittion.

Comment: @GautierC "Double submission" refers to submitting the same material to more than one journal. While there are, as I understand it, fields in which putting something on the ArXiv makes it ineligible for journal publication, I don't think that's generally referred to as "double submission". (And, in many fields, such as pure mathematics and computer science, it's considered completely normal to put papers on ArXiv before submitting them to a journal.)

Comment: @GautierC This site is full of people who _are_ pros in the field of research. It's specifically _for_ people who are pros in the field of research. Please don't post speculation when there are plenty enough people who can post _facts_.

Comment: Short answer to title: Ignore, add to spam filter.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

As you become established as a scholar, you will receive more and more of such invitations, most of which are either scams or trash publications attempting to trick you into giving them content.  A small fraction, however, will actually come from legitimate colleagues who are inviting you to a special issue, editorial, or similar such opportunity.

Thus, when receiving an invitation, you should thus begin by evaluating the quality of the venue and the person who is inviting you, just as you would if you were choosing where to submit without an invitation.  Be aware, however, that some disreputable publications will lie about the identity of people involved, and that some careless academics may have been tricked into lending their name to disreputable publications.

In the specific case of Lambert Academic Publishing, I will note that [they appear on Beale's list](https://scholarlyoa.com/2012/11/05/lambert-academic-publishing-a-must-to-avoid/) as well as a number of other highly critical analyses, including on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OmniScriptum) and [this site](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/2513/22733).  You can make up your own mind about their credibility, but I wouldn't recommend soiling your C.V. by publication with them.

Finally, to answer your question about arXiv vs. other publications: being in arXiv is fine for being accessible and citable.  If your work is good, however, I would recommend submitting to a reputable peer-reviewed journal.  If you are published in such, it will improve the reputation, notability, and value of your publication.

Comment: Good answer.  Another reason for legitimate solicitation for submissions: when people are starting new journals.  Also, in my experience legitimate invitations won't usually ask you about submitting work you've already posted online---it will just be a generic invitation for your future work---so that's another red flag.

Comment: As @Kimball says... Don't do it. It's a con.

Comment: "you should thus begin by evaluating the quality of the venue and the person who is inviting you" - see [How do you judge the quality of a journal?](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/101/how-do-you-judge-the-quality-of-a-journal) Also, [How to identify predatory publishers/journals](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/2158/how-to-identify-predatory-publishers-journals)