# Is it okay to publish your dissertation as a book and are there things that you should leave out of the book?

Tags: publications

If I have found a publisher that will publish my dissertation, is this ok, to publish your original dissertation as a book. if so are there things you should leave out of dissertation like appendix or signature page.

Comment: Do  (text)books have appendices?

Comment: The first thing every editor of a serious publisher (as opposed to a vanity press) will tell you is that a PhD thesis is not a book. I can't write a full answer now, but you should just google 'from PhD to book'. It took me several months to go from thesis to book, but YMMV.

Comment: Yes, just a warning: There are unserious publisher (Grin Verlag, AV Akademikerverlag) who write alumni that they want to publish there thesis. Be very careful and of course, discuss with your advisor!

Comment: Publishing your thesis (in a legitimate publisher) is the normal thing for certain majors in the humanities.  In fact you may spend the first 2 or 3 years after you get a university position preparing your thesis for publication, and only be tenured if/when it is published.

Comment: Following up on Haque's comment: just in case it is a similar situation, you might want to have a look at the following question (especially the accepted answer and the link within): https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/2513/is-lambert-academic-publishing-a-reputable-company.

Comment: Other than warnings about predatory publishers and miscellaneous personal anecdotes, I do not think you will get a useful Answer to your question without (a) specifying your field and (b) giving some idea about the nature of your thesis. // In math there are famous examples of important theses less than an dozen pages in length; none of those would make a suitable book. The nature of introductory material, historical perspectives, footnotes, and so on may vary greatly between an acceptable thesis and a useful book.

Comment: @SolarMike Yes, https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=Appendix

Comment: @user2768 so don’t exclude them then... and my text books have appendices, so guess what I was trying to get the OP to see...

Comment: @SolarMike Now I can understand your comment.

Comment: From my discussions with professors, many that turned their dissertations into books rewrote most of it (because dissertations typically don’t fly off the shelves) and also had to adjust their citations because there were too many in the dissertation and the publisher didn’t want to waste the ink. Look more into the publisher and then ask your advisor for advice